# JPA and JTA synchronization

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, jta

I'm developing a JPA provider that uses Mongo Driver.

I know that there are Mongo providers for JPA but I need to have more control in what's happening. I reached the point where I need to create a mechanism to synchronize JPA and JTA (Narayana), but I'm not sure how can I do it, I know that javax.transaction.Transaction has method where you register a javax.transaction.Synchronization that has two methods beforeOperation and afterOpertation. So my question is,

**where do I perform my CRUD operations where do I call the commit of JPA when JTA commit is called?** Should I perform the operations on those methods?

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Why not look at the code of one of the open source JPA providers that supports MongoDB (though the MongoDB specific part is likely irrelevant to transaction handling)? Likely the Sync tells you when you are just before commit, so then you commit your datastore code at that point ... but heck there is ample open source JPA provider code out there

Comment: Yeah you are right, thank you